# How to set location of Gtk Button in Gtk Overlay

Tags: python, gtk, alignment, overlay, gtk3

So currently I have a Gtk Overlay.  I can bring up my button that I would like to position using Gtk's `Gtk.Align.CENTER`, but I've been trying for so long now to position the button, rather than aligning it.

```
    # Overlay
    self.overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
    self.overlay.show()

    # Image
    image_pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("pics/sgcity.png")
    image_pixbuf = image_pixbuf.scale_simple(1200, 720, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)
    self.image = Gtk.Image()
    self.image.set_from_pixbuf(image_pixbuf)
    self.overlay.add(self.image)
    self.image.show()


    # Test overlay button
    self.printerimg = Gtk.Image()
    self.printerimg.set_from_file("pics/printer.png")

    self.testbutton = Gtk.Button(None)
    self.testbutton.set_image(self.printerimg)
    #self.testbutton.set_alignment(0.1, 0.9)
    #self.testbutton.set_property("width-request", 20)
    #self.testbutton.set_property("height-request", 20)
    self.testbutton.set_allocation(allocation)
    self.testbutton.set_valign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
    self.testbutton.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
    self.overlay.add_overlay(self.testbutton)
    self.testbutton.show()
    self.testbutton.set_name("testbutton")
    self.testbutton.set_opacity(0.8)



    #for i in range(len(printer_store)):
        #self.overlay.connect("get-child-position", self.get_child_position)
        #self.printbuttons[i].show()

    #def get_child_position(self, overlay, widget, allocation):
        #self.child_position_count += 1
        #for i in range(len(self.logic.get_printer_button_attributes())):
            #button_attrib = self.logic.get_printer_button_attributes()
            #allocation.x = button_attrib[i][0]
            #allocation.y = button_attrib[i][1]
            #allocation.height = button_attrib[i][2]
            #allocation.width = button_attrib[i][3]
        #print "changed"
        #return True
```

As you can see by the commented lines, I've tried using `Gtk.Widget.set_property()`, `Gtk.Widget.set_alignment()` and a few other things.  The `set_alignment()` is just setting the alignment of the image in the button to its parameters, rather than the button itself.  Any guidance as to what I should be doing to set the position of the button?  Eventually, I'll have multiple buttons at specific positions in the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Description section of the GtkOverlay documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html#GtkOverlay.description) has your answer: you either use the margin properties of the GtkWidget or the GtkOverlay's `get-child-position` signal to set the position.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying for probably 6 hours, just playing with the  `code`get-child-position signal`code`, and still havn't gotten it to work.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I was creating the handler along the lines of `self.overlay.connect("get-child-position", self.get_child_position)`, and I got that it was sending me the overlay and the button and a Gdk Rectangle.  I was having trouble figuring how to actually set the position from the rectangle though.  I tried using `set_allocation(modified_gdk_rectangle)` but didn't get that to work.  I think I'm just confused as to how I'm supposed to change the position in `self.get_child_position()`, and can't find any examples online either.  (please excuse my terrible markdown formatting)

Comment: You set the position by setting the fields of that rectangle parameter and returning `True`. I don't know if Python has a concept of a reference parameter, but that's what `allocation` is.

Comment: When you say "setting fields" you mean like `allocation.x = 25` and so on with the other rectangle member variables?  and then finish with `return True`.

Comment: welp.  I was doing it all right except the `return True` part.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Glad to see it works! Good luck from here on out.

Comment: If I have a list of buttons, and a list of attributes for the buttons (x, y, height, width).  How can I make it so the signal is called for each of the buttons?  Right now, I can only get it to work when I have one button in the overlay, otherwise it seems to shove all the buttons into the same position.  I would like to, in the `get-child-position` handler function, run a for loop and set each button's position based on the list of positions and sizes.

Comment: What are the parameters for your `get-child-position` handler in Python? I would need to know which is which to answer that.

Comment: I included the code at the bottom of the actual post in comments.  But I'm just letting it send the default parameters.

Comment: The `widget` parameter tells you which widget is being placed next.

Comment: I guess I should say, I don't understand how the overlay is choosing what widget to pass to the function.  How does it select which widget to send to the function, and when does it select it?  I understand that the `get-child-position` signal does set the position of the widget, but I don't see how its triggered or why.

Comment: It is triggered whenever the GtkOverlay needs to know where to put a child widget. This will most likely happen if the GtkOverlay's size has changed. If you need to force a relayout, you can call the GtkOverlay's `queue_resize()` method, which will act as if the GtkOverlay's size has changed and will let you get another batch of `get-child-position`s.

Comment: Thanks, that actually really helped!  I think part of it was that I just needed to step away for a bit.